# VLC or ffserver for http streaming

Tags: video, streaming

I don't like asking "OR" questions, but I can't find any comparison on the Internet. I need live http streaming using h264 in flv container.

I managed to achieve this with VLC, but with big latency. I have some problems with ffmpeg and I can not make it to work, but I wonder if would it works better then VLC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with ffmpeg, H264 in flv. It works...